# how to configure "npm run-script build" command in Nodejs package.json

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am trying to deploy nextjs based project on AWS EBS, but it is not able to run script "npm run-script build" on server, by this it makes nextjs based build package folder and can run app. here my json.

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
  }
```

when I deployed my app on server it gives following error.

> **Error: Could not find a valid build in the '/var/app/current/.next' directory! Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the
>   server.**

I need to run command "npm run-script build" before running app on server, but dosen't aware how to achieve this

Comment: depends on how u r deploying. Can you share thosee details ?

Comment: What did you set in configure environment where u set the node command?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty I dn't set any node command, I was looking for option but I dn't find any... I just upload my working code to EBS and I saw logs It trying to run next build and dosen't able  to make build and throwing error

Comment: @AritraChakraborty is there any option I can set Node command in my EBS environment

Comment: https://medium.com/commutatus/how-to-deploy-next-js-app-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-via-travis-333f66fe3102

Comment: Container option is removed to run any node command

Answer (score 1):

simply we can run multiple commands at a time.

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "npm-run-script-build && cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
  }
```